# What is the full path name of the default font file used in a Terminal

Tags: 16.04, 20.04, gnome-terminal, fonts, ubuntu-font-family

After upgrading from 16.04 to 20.04, some characters in the font used by the terminal got weird, e.g., bigger than other characters and colored other than black.  I think the easiest way for me to fix this is to find the terminal font file used on my 16.04 version and overwrite the terminal font file on my 20.04.  What are the full path names of these files?

Edit:  Let me be clear:  What is the name (full path) of the file Ubuntu uses as the default font when a Terminal window is open

Comment: What is the name of the font you are looking for? Did you look in /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the font, I think you should start with going to the *Preferences* of `gnome-terminal` and select some other font.

As regards colors, it has nothing to do with the font. The file `~/.bashrc` includes stuff which controls that.